# Change the text within a file so that the text is now corresponding to the subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, command

I need to change the text within each parameter file that is located in each subdirectory. There are 361 subdirectories.

Excerpt from parameter file:

PDB **FolderName**

From: ~josh/Documents/Model_Files/Analysis/**FolderName**

**FolderName** needs to correspond to each subdirectory in which the parameter file is located.
How do I do that for all 361 subdirectories using shell in the terminal? (I am not very familiar with batch and all of that stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -name "*" -exec sh -c 'sed -i "s,PBD FolderName,PBD $(echo $(basename $(dirname {})))," {}' \;
```

Comment: Do you mean, FolderName instead of PDB? And how does it know to use the folder name?

Comment: Here is how it knows current directory: $(echo $(basename $(dirname {}))). Try this command and see if it works for you. It replaces PDB with a subdirectory name in all files.

Comment: I need to replace FolderName, not PDB...

This is what the terminal responded for every directory:
Try `basename --help' for more information.
sh: dirname./0050/Refmt2b.out: No such file or directory

Comment: I have updated my answer to replace FolderName with a subdirectory name. You need to run this command in a directory above all your subdirectories.

Comment: Works! Thanks. The only thing is that it doesn't change the subsequent folder name in the second line of the file (From: ~josh/Documents/Model_Files/Analysis/FolderName). So, I used the command again and just changed PDB with Analysis/Folder....